# Let users visit other users (profiles) in my own written social community?

Tags: php

The thing I'm asking for is how the users can visit other users profile.

The past week I have been scripting a social network I'm doing, and I'm kind of stuck right now.

I don't know where to start and read or anything.

So I'm asking you guys to kindly help me =)

Im thinking of the url to be like `user.php?id=123` looking and get user you are visiting to show up instead of "you" wich is at `user.php`!

Live demo: http://social.swipper.org

EDIT #2:

Here's the current code i got inside user.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']) {
    include "config.php";

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $fetcher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$username'");

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetcher)){
        $firstname = $data['firstname'];
        $lastname = $data['lastname'];
        $gender = $data['gender'];
    }

    // get user's profile image
    if (file_exists("users/$username/profile.jpg")) {
            $userPhoto = "<img class='pic' src='users/$username/profile.jpg' width='90%' height='30%' />";
    }
    elseif (!file_exists("users/$username/profile.jpg")) {
            $userPhoto = "<img class='pic' src='http://www.uavmedia.com/portal/images/no-user.jpg' width='90%' height='30%' />";
    }
    // the user's profile image is fetched

    // henter profil text
    $file = "users/$username/bio.txt"; 
    $contents = file($file);
    $profile_text = implode($contents);
    // ferdig å hente profil text, vil nå echo ut profil siden.
    // henter profil stilsett
    $file2 = "users/$username/style.css"; 
    $contents2 = file($file2);
    $profile_style = implode($contents2);
    // ferdig å hente profil stilsett.

    echo
    "
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Social FW</title>
        <meta name='Description' content='A Social network for everyone. Come join us!' />
        <meta name='Keywords' content='Social, Network, Framewerk, Framework, FW, Open-Source, Free' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='user_files/style.css' media='screen' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='SFW_files/style2.css' media='screen' />
<style type='text/css'>
$profile_style
</style>
        <link rel='icon' href='SFW_files/favicon.ico' media='screen' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='SFW_files/scripts/login.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='top'>
        <h1>Swipper.org</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='side-menu'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='user.php'><b>".$username."</b></a></li><br/>
            <li><a href=''>Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Guestbook</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Friends</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>Pictures</a></li><br />

            <div id='showOptions'><li><a href='#'>Edit Profile</a></li></div>
                <div id='editOptions' style='display:none;'>
<pre class='user_info'><b>></b><a href='changeText.php'>Edit Profile Text</a>
<b>></b><a href='changeCss.php'>Edit Stylesheet(CSS)</a>
<b>></b><a href='changeProfilePic.php'>Change Profile Image</a></pre>
                </div><br />
            <a href='logout.php'><b>Logout</b></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='side-left'>
    <!-- START USER PIC --!>
            <center>
                $userPhoto<br />
            </center>
    <!-- END USER PIC --!>
    <!-- START USER INFO --!>
            <br />
            <h3><pre class='user_info'>User Info</pre></h3>
                <pre class='user_info'>Name: ".$firstname." ".$lastname."<br />Sex : $gender</pre>
    <!-- END USER INFO --!>
    </div>
    <div id='box_center'>
        <h2 style='font-size:30px;' align='center'>$username</h2>
            <hr />
        <br />
        $profile_text
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
        <p align='center'>Swipper.org &copy; All rights reserved. 2010-2012</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    ";
}
else {
    die("You need to login first or register. You can register/login <a href='index.php'>here</a>!");
}
?>
```

and when the url is like: user.php?id=3 i want to get the user with userid 3 to show up, and get user #3's information instead of the "user" who wants to visit other people.

Comment: user.php?id=123 you mean when you enter your profile? or another one's profile that you don't know how to make the link look like this?

Comment: whay have you tried? Any code snippets? How do you get the user currently from the database?

Comment: Even with your edit, it's still not clear. Where exactly are you stuck, with your tables schema, with the friendship checking functionality, with what exactly are you stuck?

Comment: user.php is suppose to be the "person" that have logged in. and user.php?id=123 is suppose to pick up data from the database and change the images, profile text, and stuff like that to the user it want to visit. I'd may provide the user.php i got now?

Comment: Im stuck with how i can let users visit eachothers..

Comment: provide relevant code snippet not an entire page

Comment: so exactly what you want to know? you can do this for both visitors and the logged in user too. And then can check if the user is same as logged user and show data accordingly.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted instead of writing "SOLVED" in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you listing all the users some where? if you are the href needs to be something like

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SLECET * FROM userinfo");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo "<a href='users.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>"
    }
```

then in users.php

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
            if(is_numeric($_REQUEST['id'])){
                $uid = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id='" . $uid . "' LIMIT 1");
            }
        } else {
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' LIMIT 1");
        }
```

then later your html can use that with a fetch_assoc($sql)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?>'s Profile</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

simple example. but i think you get the picture, message me on FB for more on this Stian

Comment: the request vars can be what ever you want as long as you can validate it against mysql. its all up to you, but you need to escape the users input

Answer (score 0):

Make your query like

```
$userID = $_GET['id'];
$fetcher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE userID='$userID'");
```

and you can accordingly show data for any user with the valid user ID as given in url.

if profile can be viewed without login too then there is no need of session and if its compulsory only check if isset or not. if you are passing username in url as

```
user.php?user=test1
```

then your query will be like

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
$fetcher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$username'");
```

Hope now its more clear to u.

Comment: The value from $_GET **must** be casted to int, like so: $userID=(int)$_GET['id'];
It is a big security flaw otherwise

Comment: One more question, the $username variable is still suppose to be the same?

Comment: if you want it to be from username then in url you can use username instead of id of user. Make username unique too then.

Comment: i have a check on the register process code, wich check if the username already exsists in the database. i'll explore with the code you gave me =) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should be your answer:

```
if (isset($_GET['username']){
    $username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
}else{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
$fetcher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$username'");
if (mysql_num_rows() == 0){
    $username = '';
    echo 'Username not found'; die();
}
```